# UBUNTU: sudo apt-get update error

Tags: ubuntu, error-handling, apt-get

I need help, when I run **sudo apt-get update** this is the result

```
can't create /var/cache/apt-show-versions/files: No such file or directory at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 196.
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following  signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available:  NO_PUBKEY 32B18A1260D8DA0B
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'test -x /usr/bin/apt-show-versions || exit 0 ; apt-show-versions -i'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

how can I solve this.

Comment: Have you tried sudo apt-get clean? Then execute the update

Comment: @ductiletoaster yes sir. I made that

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question; try https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: @KeithThompson Agreed. I found a related answer on that site. Probably a better place to go

Comment: @KeithThompson User found their answer on another forum. I edited the Question to reflect this fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be experiencing a few separate problems but for the GPG error try following [this example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey). Post back once you have and I'll try to work with you further.

Comment: thanks GPG error already gone. but still i have this error
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'test -x /usr/bin/apt-show-versions || exit 0 ; apt-show-versions -i'
E: Sub-process returned an error code

Comment: can't create /var/cache/apt-show-versions/files: No such file or directory at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 196.